# Google Social SignIn with Spring Boot with Specific Domain

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-plus, spring-social

I'm integrating Google+ Signin with Spring Social & Boot.

However it allows me to signIn with `@gmail.com` domain, but now I want to setup signIn option only for organization. i.e. `username@googledomain.com`

How can we add specific domain name validation for Spring Social?

Answer (score 0):

When you implement your own signin adapter you have the option to fetch the user profile from the identity provider and with that you are able to validate the e-mail address. The return string here represents the URL to redirect to, so when their e-mail address not matches the domain you could redirect them to an error page without signin them in.

```
@Component
public class SocialSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsTransformer userDetailsTransformer;

    @Autowired
    public SocialSignInAdapter(UserDetailsTransformer userDetailsTransformer) {
        this.userDetailsTransformer = userDetailsTransformer;
    }

    @Override
    public String signIn(String localUserId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
        if (connection.fetchUserProfile().getEmail().matches("^.*@googledomain.com$")) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetailsTransformer.convert(connection), null,
                            Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(String.format("%s_USER", connection.getKey().getProviderId())))));
            return "/";
        } else {
            return "/some-error-page";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I'll check it and let you know :)

Comment: I had an ongoing project which has spring social in it so I tested it there. The solution could be smaller than this one.

Comment: I have tried with this solution, but the problem is i want to authentic email address before signing in google !

Can we set some validation on google domain side ?

Comment: This might help if you could tweak spring social to use this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param

Comment: I have already checked this param "HD" but as far as i have checked code, Spring Social doesn't provide any facility to provide HD param.